# cassandra table modeling - updating existing columns in bulk and adding new columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, nosql

I am migrating RDBMS tables to cassandra. We track customers who are subscribing to different categories. There are some categories already but some categories maybe added new incourse of time. Right now we are joining the tables.

```
details table1 - columns 
       custid, name , address, phone
details table2 - custid, cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4
category details - catid, catname, catregion, catdescription, iscatmanadatory
```

In Cassandra I am trying to keep the customer id and name as primary keys. I am planning to keep categories subscribed by customer in a map. But if any new categories are added, will collection columns create any bottlenecks ?

Comment: How many category a customer can subscribed ?

Comment: A customer can subscribe to any number of categories.